# How to make a widget flexible on different screens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 6 widgets with icons and text. I placed the icon and text in the Stack widget so that I could move the icon to the text. But I ran into a problem, if you look at a narrow screen, then the text will fit on the icon and this is a problem. How do I make this widget flexible if the screen is narrow, then the text does not fit on the icon?

```
Column(
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Wrap(
                              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                              spacing: 10,
                              children: [
                                _mainWidget(
                                  size,
                                  constants.Assets.main,
                                  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 3+ h',
                                  textStyleDescription,
                                  leftText: 27,
                                ),
                                _mainWidget(
                                  size,
                                  constants.Assets.main,
                                  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text  2 h',
                                  textStyleDescription,
                                  leftText: 27,
                                ),
                                _mainWidget(
                                  size,
                                  constants.Assets.main,
                                  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy 1 h',
                                  textStyleDescription,
                                  leftText: 27,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        ],
                      ),




 Widget _mainWidget(
          Size size, String assetName, String title, TextStyle titleStyle,
          {double topText = 20, double leftText = 22, double widthText = 65}) =>
      SizedBox(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                assetName,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: leftText,
              top: topText,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: widthText,
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: titleStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Comment: could you add the ui design of what you want?

Comment: You can use Flexible or Expanded Widgets to create flex ui.

Comment: The design needs the same, but so that when the device width changes, the text does not move, but is fixed. Because when changing the width of the screen, I now have the text on the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `screen size` to set the `width` and `height` of your `SizedBox`:

```
Widget _mainWidget(
          Size size, String assetName, String title, TextStyle titleStyle,
          {double topText = 20, double leftText = 22, double widthText = 65}){

   var size = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size;

   return SizedBox(
        width: size.width /6,
        height: size.width /6,
        ...
   );
}
```

you can play with `size.width /6` to get what suitable for you.

Comment: could you help me with one more question, i don't know how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74014106/how-to-fill-a-line-depending-on-a-percentage-using-canvas-in-flutter

Comment: glad to help. sorry I don't have much knowledge about CustomPaint.