# How to fill a line depending on a percentage using Canvas in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas

I have a map that displays markers with data. On the right side of the marker there is an indicator in the form of a purple stripe. I need to make this indicator dynamic so that I can set a value in % and, depending on this value, the bar is filled with red. If the value is 100% then a completely red stripe, if 60% then a little more than half of the red color and the rest is green. I was drawing a strip using Canvas, but now I'm facing the problem that I don't know how can I make this strip dynamic, two-colored and dependent on %? I will be grateful for help

```
class PointPainter extends CustomPainter {
  PointPainter({this.isClosed = false});

  final bool isClosed;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final strokeWidthThin = size.width * 0.07;
    Paint paintMain = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidthThin
      ..color = constants.Colors.purpleMain;

    Paint paintPurpleThin = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidthThin
      ..color = constants.Colors.purpleMain;

    Paint paintPurpleBold = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = size.width * 0.16
      ..color = constants.Colors.purpleMain;

    Paint paintGreen = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidthThin
      ..color = constants.Colors.purpleMainDark.withOpacity(isClosed ? 0.5 : 1);

    Paint paintTransparent = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = size.width * 0.04
      ..color = constants.Colors.purpleMainDark;

    final pathMain = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width / 2, size.height * 1.05)
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 - size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.4)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - size.width * 0.2, size.height * 0.3),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: const Radius.circular(0.9),
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 + size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.4);

    final pathGreen = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width / 2 + size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.4)
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - size.width * 0.22, size.height * 0.26),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: const Radius.circular(0.9),
      );

    final pathPurpleThin = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width / 2, size.height * 1.05)
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 - size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.4);

    final pathPurpleBold = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width * 0.54, size.height * 1.03)
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 + size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.45);

    final pathTransparent = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width * 0.44, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width * 0.58, size.height * 0.68);

    pathMain.close();
    pathGreen.close();
    pathPurpleThin.close();
    pathTransparent.close();

    if (!isClosed) {
      canvas.drawPath(pathMain, paintMain);
      canvas.drawPath(pathGreen, paintGreen);
      canvas.drawPath(pathPurpleThin, paintPurpleThin);
      canvas.drawPath(pathTransparent, paintTransparent);
    }

    canvas.drawPath(pathPurpleBold, paintPurpleBold);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**body**

```
      ClipPath(
        clipper: PointClipper(),
        child: Container(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          color: constants.Colors.purpleMainDark,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: PointPainter(isClosed: isClosed),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

**point_clipper**

```
class PointClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  PointClipper();

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    //top
    final path0 = Path();
      path0..moveTo(size.width / 2, size.height * 0.4)
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 - size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.4)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - size.width * 0.2, size.height * 0.3),
        clockwise: true,
        radius: const Radius.circular(0.9),
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 + size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.4);
      path0.close();

    //bottom
    path0.moveTo(size.width * 0.43, size.height * 0.9);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 1.1,
        size.width * 0.57, size.height * 0.9);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.6, size.height * 0.9,
        size.width * 0.43, size.height * 0.9);
    path0.close();

    //middle
    path0..moveTo(size.width * 0.43, size.height * 0.9)
      ..lineTo(size.width * 0.57, size.height * 0.9)
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 + size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.4)
    ..lineTo(size.width / 2 - size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.4);
    path0.close();

    return path0;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(PointClipper oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: could you also add the part you are using PointPainter?